# Regex to determine if the value is valid in JS returns null

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if a value is a valid pair of digits, having a dot and has zero, one or two digits behind the dot.

At first I tried to use `parseFloat()` which seemed okay because I could evaluate the result for NaN. Except that if a value like 11aa.01 was given it would return 11 and not NaN.

After that I went to `match()` to see if a regular expression could do the trick. I thought `var mIsFloat = $('#Price').val().match('/\d+\.\d{0,2}/');` would do the trick but when I `console.log()` the result I get `null`.

Am I overlooking some obvious thing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should pass `match` a *regular expression*, not a *string*.

```
match(/\d+\.\d{0,2}/);
```

Second, this isn't anchored to the ends of the string you are matching against, so it will quite happily say that `"aa1.23bb"` matches.

```
match(/^\d+\.\d{0,2}$/);
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Small thing: the ^ was supposed to be placed after the first /. +1A

Answer (score 0):

The `.match` function returns either an array of matches, or `null` if no matches were found. So I'd suggest this change to your example:

`var mIsFloat = ($('#Price').val().match(/\d+\.\d{0,2}/) !== null);`